# Transferring a changed value from one method to another

Tags: java

so what I am trying to do it take the Value that I am allowing my BargainCustomer to spend, and get him/her to buy the first car they see in the list under that price. Then take the remaining money and buy whatever features they can. However, I do not remember how to call my value for the remaining money from my other method. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BargainCustomer implements Customer
{
   public Car purchase(ArrayList<Car> listOfCars)
   {
       int moneyToSpend = 35000;
       int moneyLeft = 0;
       int indexLocation = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < listOfCars.size(); i++)
       {
           if (listOfCars.get(i).getBasePrice()<moneyToSpend)
           {
               moneyLeft=moneyToSpend-listOfCars.get(i).getBasePrice();
               indexLocation = i;
           }
       }
       return listOfCars.get(indexLocation);
   } 

   public void upgrade(Car g)
   {
       int featuresMoney = moneyLeft;
       for (int i = 0; i < g.getFeatures().size(); i++)
       {
           moneyLeft-=g.getFeatures().get(i).getCost();
           if (moneyLeft>=0)
           {
               g.getFeatures().get(i).purchase();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Ideally the buyer should only buy what they can afford with the remaining money.

Comment: Move the `moneyLeft` declaration to the class level. `moneyToSpend` probably belongs there too. Really you only need one of them.

Comment: Yes but that doesnt give me the new value of moneyLeft after the first method is used for the second method. I want moneyLeft to be the value of moneyToSpend minus basePrice of the car so that moneyLeft can be the money for the cars features in the second method.

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: The problem is that its not resulting in any of the features being purchased, even though I know for a fact some should be as they fit within the remaining amount.

Comment: Well there could be any number of reasons for that, starting with the possibility that you misunderstood my suggestion, and ending with the bug in your code where you subtract the feature cost before checking whether it's affordable.

Comment: Well, that fixed it. I didnt see that bug. Thank you for your help

Comment: Smells hardly like: "please do this homework assignment for me". @shmosel is correct, and without changes in the interface, this is your best bet. Read about instance variables, and check your code

Comment: That wasn't intentional. I was fairly sure my code was correct, I just wasnt sure why the compiler was telling me otherwise. I had also forgotten about shmosels suggestion

Answer (score 0):

depending on your logic, it would be best to just chain the calls:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BargainCustomer implements Customer
{
   public Car purchase(ArrayList<Car> listOfCars)
   {
       int moneyToSpend = 35000;
       int moneyLeft = 0;
       int indexLocation = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < listOfCars.size(); i++)
       {
           if (listOfCars.get(i).getBasePrice()<moneyToSpend)
           {
               moneyLeft=moneyToSpend-listOfCars.get(i).getBasePrice();
               indexLocation = i;
           }
       }
       return upgrade(listOfCars.get(indexLocation), moneyLeft);
   } 

   public void upgrade(Car g, int moneyLeft)
   {
       int featuresMoney = moneyLeft;
       for (int i = 0; i < g.getFeatures().size(); i++)
       {
           moneyLeft-=g.getFeatures().get(i).getCost();
           if (moneyLeft>=0)
           {
               g.getFeatures().get(i).purchase();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

This will just give you the car with all the features right away, if you need steps in between, you can just use a class variable, or calculate it again. Since you return the car, you can just substract the car price from the moneyToSpend

P.S. are you sure, int is the right choose for money in your case ? it will not handle comma values. Depending on currency, prices are rarly ever without fractions.

Comment: No that just results in an error that "BargainCustomer is not abstract and does not override abstract method upgrade(Car) in Customer (I forgot that was an abstract in my interface)

Comment: In terms of this case, all prices are in integers for some reason. Im just going as I see it and double is not necessary for this for some reason

Comment: Im not allowed to

Comment: Sidenote: "Integer" money is a common way to prevent rounding errors when handling currency.

Comment: That's why i stated it as a question, it was just to ask if he is sure

Comment: since you are not allowed to change the interface, you have to make moneyLeft an instance variable, according to @shmosel's comment to your question

Comment: That apparently wasn't the only problem. There was a bug in my code which was that I was subtracting the cost before checking to see if it could be afforded.